# Why is my character suddenly attacking really slowly?

Tags: hinterland

My character is performing his (visual) attacks much slower than before. I'm pretty sure it also affects the dps.

With the following equipment/skill set:

- Dagger (2att, speed: very fast)
- Chainmail (4def)
- Defensive Lesser Ring of Power (1att, 1def)
- Resourceful (extra food)
- Observant (more gold from loot)
- Touch (increase health)

I'm moving about 3-5 times slower than my follower with a Hammer (speed: slow) and a Full Shield (speed: slow). I would estimate that my hero is performing an attack about every 1.5s.

I also dropped everything I was wearing and went back to just the Main Gauche, with no effect.

Any idea what might cause this? I know that in the beginning, I thought I had to click per blow, so I hammered the right mouse button. Then I figured out that apparently, I just have to assign a target and then the attack will repeat automatically, so I'm just 'marking' targets. Going back to repeatedly pressing that button doesn't seem to help either, though.

Comment: Is it the whole game that is slow, or just the attacking ?

Comment: Just *my* attacking. As I said, my followers are still attacking at normal speed (although I use a 'very fast' weapon and he uses a 'slow' weapon). Just the character I play seems to be affected by this.

Comment: What game does this question relate to?

Comment: @LordScree Hinterland. It was tagged that way originally. I don't know how the tag disappeared and I don't see a trace of the removal in the revision history.

Comment: @Cort Tags expire after ~6 months or so, if there is only a single question that uses it.  That way, little used tags get removed automatically.

Comment: What kind of video card do you have for your computer and have you changed it at all before this happened???

Comment: @AmyFreeman No, that was during a single game session, without exiting the game in between.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of things that could contribute to this: starting background (what we'd call class in many other games), equipment, and in-game effects. Background isn't going to be the cause here if by "before" you mean "earlier in this game", but I'm including that info just in case.

There are three backgrounds whose attack speed is slower than expected with a Dagger (a fourth, Courtesan, is slower only with two-handed melee weapons):

- Seneschal has extremely slow attack speed
- Architect has diminished attack speed
- Elven Archer is slow with melee weapons

The Seneschal is most likely to create a noticeable difference between how you expected to attack and how you are attacking.

Although you aren't carrying a shield and your follower is, I'll mention this as well: there is a theory that attack speed is affected by anything that has a speed, so for example, that Full Shield may be slowing your follower's attack speed (which would mean something else has a much greater impact on your speed). [This thread](http://tiltedmill.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=18732) on the Hinterland forums mentions theories about both damage and attack speed, and it as well as others brings up the possibility of armor/shield/items slowing attack speed.

The one remaining category is in-game effects. Orc Shamans, in particular, will cast some spells that seem to be curses ... but even those don't last particularly long. (It's been a while since I've been poisoned; I believe that does slow you down, but I could be wrong.)

And you are correct - there's no need to keep clicking (or as I used to do, holding down the button). In Hinterland, clicking simply chooses a target, and you'll continue to attack it until it dies or you do.

So ... hard to say, in your case?